# Retrieve data from firebase to android

Tags: javascript, php, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have built an android app with Firebase login. There are various types of login like employee, manager etc. When the user logins in he/she should be able to see his works for the day and click on the completed button when the work is completed. How to post data to Firebase from a website and retrieve the data from Firebase to Android app based on the login?

Comment: can you post code what do you tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase supports the use of real-time database for android. You can refer to the usage here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/

You can setup the data and retrieve it from firebase. Data will update automatically in real time.